# ASP.Net - Compressão de arquivos JavaScript / Text GZip

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp, gzip

Boa tarde, estou com muita dificuldade na configuração da compressão de tráfego usando o `GZip`. Abaixo está os passos que eu já segui para efetivar a compressão:

1. Já ativei os recursos do windows relacionados a compressão de arquivos na web;
2. Adicionei o seguinte código no meu `Web.Config` para que consiga ler os arquivos corretamente e realizar a compressão:

```js
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\websites\_compressed" minFileSizeForComp="0">  
    <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
    <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

3. Já ativei a `"Compactação dinâmica"` e `"Compactação estática"` no console do `IIS`;
4. Já tentei retirar o tamanho mínimo do arquivo para realizar a compressão e ver se realmente seria o tamanho dos arquivos.
5. Já tentei também:

```js
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
```

**Será que alguém pode me ajudar?**

*Obs: Já visitei vários outros posts da comunidade relacionado ao assunto, porém nenhuma resposta resolveu meu problema.*

Configurações IIS:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--

    IIS configuration sections.

    For schema documentation, see
    %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\schema\IIS_schema.xml.
    
    Please make a backup of this file before making any changes to it.

-->

<configuration>

    <!--

        The <configSections> section controls the registration of sections.
        Section is the basic unit of deployment, locking, searching and
        containment for configuration settings.
        
        Every section belongs to one section group.
        A section group is a container of logically-related sections.
        
        Sections cannot be nested.
        Section groups may be nested.
        
        <section
            name=""  [Required, Collection Key] [XML name of the section]
            allowDefinition="Everywhere" [MachineOnly|MachineToApplication|AppHostOnly|Everywhere] [Level where it can be set]
            overrideModeDefault="Allow"  [Allow|Deny] [Default delegation mode]
            allowLocation="true"  [true|false] [Allowed in location tags]
        />
        
        The recommended way to unlock sections is by using a location tag:
        <location path="Default Web Site" overrideMode="Allow">
            <system.webServer>
                <asp />
            </system.webServer>
        </location>

    -->
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.applicationHost">
            <section name="applicationPools" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="configHistory" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="customMetadata" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="listenerAdapters" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="log" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="serviceAutoStartProviders" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="sites" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="webLimits" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        </sectionGroup>

        <sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
            <section name="asp" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="caching" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            <section name="cgi" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="defaultDocument" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            <section name="directoryBrowse" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            <section name="fastCgi" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="globalModules" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="httpCompression" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="httpErrors" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            <section name="httpLogging" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="httpProtocol" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            <section name="httpRedirect" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            <section name="httpTracing" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="isapiFilters" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="modules" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="applicationInitialization" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            <section name="odbcLogging" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <sectionGroup name="security">
                <section name="access" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
                <section name="applicationDependencies" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
                <sectionGroup name="authentication">
                    <section name="anonymousAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
                    <section name="basicAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
                    <section name="clientCertificateMappingAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
                    <section name="digestAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
                    <section name="iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
                    <section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
                </sectionGroup>
                <section name="authorization" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
                <section name="ipSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
                <section name="dynamicIpSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
                <section name="isapiCgiRestriction" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
                <section name="requestFiltering" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            </sectionGroup>
            <section name="serverRuntime" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="serverSideInclude" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <section name="staticContent" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            <sectionGroup name="tracing">
                <section name="traceFailedRequests" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
                <section name="traceProviderDefinitions" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            </sectionGroup>
            <section name="urlCompression" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            <section name="validation" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            <sectionGroup name="webdav">
                <section name="globalSettings" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
                <section name="authoring" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
                <section name="authoringRules" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            </sectionGroup>
            <section name="webSocket" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
        </sectionGroup>
        <sectionGroup name="system.ftpServer">
            <section name="log" overrideModeDefault="Deny" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" />
            <section name="firewallSupport" overrideModeDefault="Deny" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" />
            <section name="caching" overrideModeDefault="Deny" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" />
            <section name="providerDefinitions" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            <sectionGroup name="security">
                <section name="ipSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
                <section name="requestFiltering" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
                <section name="authorization" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
                <section name="authentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            </sectionGroup>
            <section name="serverRuntime" overrideModeDefault="Deny" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <configProtectedData>
        <providers>
            <add name="IISWASOnlyRsaProvider" type="" description="Uses RsaCryptoServiceProvider to encrypt and decrypt" keyContainerName="iisWasKey" cspProviderName="" useMachineContainer="true" useOAEP="false" />
            <add name="IISCngProvider" type="Microsoft.ApplicationHost.CngProtectedConfigurationProvider" description="Uses Win32 Crypto CNG to encrypt and decrypt" keyContainerName="iisCngConfigurationKey" useMachineContainer="true" />
            <add name="IISWASOnlyCngProvider" type="Microsoft.ApplicationHost.CngProtectedConfigurationProvider" description="(WAS Only) Uses Win32 Crypto CNG to encrypt and decrypt" keyContainerName="iisCngWasKey" useMachineContainer="true" />
            <add name="AesProvider" type="Microsoft.ApplicationHost.AesProtectedConfigurationProvider" description="Uses an AES session key to encrypt and decrypt" keyContainerName="iisConfigurationKey" cspProviderName="" useOAEP="false" useMachineContainer="true" sessionKey="AQIAAA5mAAAApAAAE1i9v5I5UGXhWB12Q+czeTUqMSFI0GVRdtzVBlPFS1s5WIuIvTSKLmC+L19pFgdM65vwTQxPEyUzk3tiut0MdunQSIzegA1MQFmdvIAL8TMh+V5xIaqINRHqErzfQikmci58TwabaAqNN6jD/VPGGow7DK0a6m7bhgycfteqXFjYNxaejCAmTCSaYTSSUX0h6r1drzV6YSTbLXvl4bw5L3a7o91pgq153QeXGixQ5u001Gj9atMW4ZErYo8DOPEyO5MpgImDP10aUa44PNJaMsFD11brH6RjC3KFB1SeFdOcboo6L25lT73VKC4b2MMMyMprLYA3+pYYi3doGFd7WQ==" />
            <add name="IISWASOnlyAesProvider" type="Microsoft.ApplicationHost.AesProtectedConfigurationProvider" description="Uses an AES session key to encrypt and decrypt" keyContainerName="iisWasKey" cspProviderName="" useOAEP="false" useMachineContainer="true" sessionKey="AQIAAA5mAAAApAAAsXT7v6ghQu+IjV71ic8/nMeJsyrVE+9Uum4L10feXT1+fVTf8Foj5eYQp0HExmhJHVD6q5hqso3HkxibEfvQRZsD18QXvHp4E5B6p6L4ZYJQqL8LS/k/crs2Eiz8oZASEmRM9rOSjRdcOaLxUR/mHx4DlpHVEp1sG0EepCahOKtMFaoXKWZoqYKMZIDsqtvVZLZf8Q17Co/GIHB/A1+0KX9Sz56TnD7m5OhVA2l3gUy1cQ33GdkHB90uMBnuWQFuxgxIg5f2JgRcJaYnLfMOyG1AAGewWzifLqjHuRj5OPgi9hhcZCk6qMCwUSZyAa8iEqyR1G72B/MNzkUErJGixQ==" />
        </providers>
    </configProtectedData>

    <system.applicationHost>

        <applicationPools>
            <add name="DefaultAppPool" />
            <applicationPoolDefaults managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0">
                <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="false" />
            </applicationPoolDefaults>
        </applicationPools>

        <!--

          The <customMetadata> section is used internally by the Admin Base Objects
          (ABO) Compatibility component. Please do not modify its content.

        -->
        <customMetadata>
            <key path="LM/W3SVC/INFO">
                <property id="4012" dataType="String" userType="1" attributes="Inherit" value="Formato do Arquivo de Log Comum do NCSA,Formato do Arquivo de Log do Microsoft IIS,Formato do Arquivo de Log Estendido do W3C,Log de ODBC" />
                <property id="2120" dataType="MultiSZ" userType="1" attributes="None" value="400,0,,,0&#xA;" />
            </key>
        </customMetadata>

        <!--

          The <listenerAdapters> section defines the protocols with which the
          Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) binds.

        -->
        <listenerAdapters>
            <add name="http" />
        </listenerAdapters>

        <log>
            <centralBinaryLogFile enabled="true" directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles" />
            <centralW3CLogFile enabled="true" directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles" />
        </log>

        <sites>
            <site name="Default Web Site" id="1">
                <application path="/">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
            <siteDefaults>
                <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles" />
                <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles" />
            </siteDefaults>
            <applicationDefaults applicationPool="DefaultAppPool" />
            <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
        </sites>

        <webLimits />

    </system.applicationHost>

    <system.webServer>

        <asp />

        <caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true">
        </caching>

        <cgi />

        <defaultDocument />

        <directoryBrowse />

        <fastCgi />

        <!--

          The <globalModules> section defines all native-code modules.
          To enable a module, specify it in the <modules> section.

        -->
        <globalModules>
            <add name="UriCacheModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\cachuri.dll" />
            <add name="FileCacheModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\cachfile.dll" />
            <add name="TokenCacheModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\cachtokn.dll" />
            <add name="HttpCacheModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\cachhttp.dll" />
            <add name="DynamicCompressionModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\compdyn.dll" />
            <add name="StaticCompressionModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\compstat.dll" />
            <add name="ProtocolSupportModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\protsup.dll" />
            <add name="AnonymousAuthenticationModule" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\authanon.dll" />
        </globalModules>

        <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
            <add name="TRACEVerbHandler" path="*" verb="TRACE" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" />
            <add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" />
        </handlers>

    <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
      <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" staticCompressionLevel="9" />
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </dynamicTypes>
      <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>

        <httpErrors />

        <httpLogging />

        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <clear />
            </customHeaders>
            <redirectHeaders>
                <clear />
            </redirectHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>

        <httpRedirect />

        <httpTracing />

        <isapiFilters />

        <modules>
            <add name="HttpCacheModule" lockItem="true" />
            <add name="DynamicCompressionModule" lockItem="true" />
            <add name="StaticCompressionModule" lockItem="true" />
            <add name="ProtocolSupportModule" lockItem="true" />
            <add name="AnonymousAuthenticationModule" lockItem="true" />
        </modules>

        <odbcLogging />

        <security>

            <access sslFlags="None" />

            <applicationDependencies />

            <authentication>

                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" userName="IUSR" />

                <basicAuthentication />

                <clientCertificateMappingAuthentication />

                <digestAuthentication />

                <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication />

                <windowsAuthentication />

            </authentication>

            <authorization />

            <ipSecurity />

            <isapiCgiRestriction />

            <requestFiltering />

        </security>

        <serverRuntime />

        <serverSideInclude />

        <staticContent />

        <tracing>

            <traceFailedRequests />

            <traceProviderDefinitions />

        </tracing>

        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />

        <validation />

    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei a solução alterando o `applicationHost.config` pertencente ao projeto que está em desenvolvimento.

**Texto original**

> ApplicationHost.config is the root file of the configuration system
>   when you are using IIS 7 and above. It includes definitions of all
>   sites, applications, virtual directories and application pools, as
>   well as global defaults for the web server settings (similar to
>   machine.config and the root web.config for .NET Framework settings).

**Tradução (Portugues-PT)**

> ApplicationHost.config é o arquivo raiz do sistema de configuração quando você está usando o IIS 7 e acima. Ele inclui definições de todos os sites, aplicativos, diretórios virtuais e pools de aplicativos, bem como padrões globais para as configurações do servidor da Web (semelhante ao machine.config e ao web.config raiz para as configurações do .NET Framework).

Eu havia configurado o `applicationHost.config` que existia na pasta do `IIS` e não o existente na pasta do projeto justamente por desconhece-lo. Ao iniciar a aplicação pelo VS, ele leva este arquivo em consideração e nele estava comentado a parte de compressão dos arquivos. Bastou descomentar e tudo funcionou!

**Caminho do arquivo de configuração:**

```js
~\SEU_PROJETO\.vs\config\applicationhost.config
```